# Firestore Observables: Trying to merge data that comes from multiple levels inside combineLatest()

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

So I've got a bit of a situation where I'm trying to pull data from multiple different tables in my Firestore database. I've done this kind of thing with Firebase realtime database, however I think I'm doing something wrong here, or I'm missing something.

I have a function that runs a number of layered `combineLatest` and `switchMap` functions to grab data and return it all the way to the original caller of the function like so:

```
/**
   *  Get the groupings and then get the mapping data for each
   */
  getGroupingsData(userId, businessAccountId, duration) {

    // User's access token
    let at = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

    return Observable.combineLatest(
      Observable.fromPromise(this.getPagesForUser()),
      this.getGroupingsForUserAndAccount(userId, businessAccountId)
    ).switchMap(results => {

      let fbPages = results[0].data;
      let groupings = results[1];

      // Let's iterate through each mapping
      return Observable.combineLatest(
        groupings.map(grouping => {
          let group = grouping.payload.doc.data();
          return Observable.combineLatest(
            group.mappings.map(mapping => {
              return this.getMappingData(mapping.id).switchMap(data => {
                let mapData = data.payload.data();
                let pageAccessToken = '';

                // Loop through pages and see if one can find a matching fb ID
                fbPages.forEach(page => {

                  // We have a match, add the page access token to the mapping
                  if(page.id === mapData.page.id) {
                    pageAccessToken = page.access_token;
                  }
                });

                // Get the data for the duration
                return Observable.combineLatest(
                  this.getFacebookAdAccountStats(mapData.ad_account.id),
                  Observable.fromPromise(this.getInsightsForPage(mapData.page.id, pageAccessToken, duration))
                )
                .switchMap(theData => {
                  let adAccountStatsData = theData[0];
                  let fbPageInsightsData = theData[1];
                  let mappingAdData = {
                    ad_account: {
                      insights: {}
                    },
                    page: {}
                  }
                  mappingAdData['ad_account']['insights'] = adAccountStatsData;
                  mappingAdData['page']['insights'] = {
                    reach_total_paid: fbPageInsightsData[0].data[0].values[1].value,
                    reach_total_organic: fbPageInsightsData[1].data[0].values[1].value,
                    impressions_total_paid: fbPageInsightsData[2].data[0].values[1].value,
                    impressions_total_organic: fbPageInsightsData[3].data[0].values[1].value,
                    engaged_users_total: fbPageInsightsData[4].data[0].values[1].value,
                  };

                  return Observable.of(mappingAdData);
                })
              })
            })
          )
        })
      )
    })
  }
```

In this particular example, the data from the deepest nested `combineLatest()` function is bubbling up correctly, however there are some pieces of data that I want to attach to it before it reaches the `.subscribe()` that I have in another component.

Is there any way I can take the data from that deepest level data and add it to an object that contains data from higher up in the function that I can then return to the calling function? I realize this is a bit of a complex query I'm trying to piece together, but is there something that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe "merge" operator with the observer to attach the data. If data to be attached is also a observable, then it's really simple just pipe the new observable and return the observable. Else if it's static data or from some other source, first convert it into a observable by using "of" operator and then pipe it your desired observable.

```
result$ = first$.pipe(merge(second$))
```